# gitlab ci fails to deploy pages after commit to repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a CI pipeline for python project. In a nutshell it is supposed to do the following:

- Generate CHANGELOG.md based on conventional commits (using python-semantic-release)
- Increment version and create a version tag
- Commit and push modified CHANGELOG.md along with a version tag back into the repo
- Build documentation using sphinx
- Publish documentation using gitlab pages
- Deploy the app to staging environment (auto)
- Deploy the app to prod environment (manual)

I am facing a strange error where `deploy:pages` step fails only if `release` step has pushed to original repo.

I provide a simpliefied version of my .`gitlab-ci.yml` at the end of the post. For simplicity I removed the steps responsible for deployment. Those don't cause me any problems.

If I completely remove `release` step, then `pages` and `pages:deploy` succeed (but that is not what I want as I want to generate a release before building the docs):

[image]

If I keep `release` step, then `pages` succeeds but `pages:deploy` fails with this message:

[image]

If I just comment out these two lines...

```
    - git push -o ci.skip "https://GITLAB_CI_TOKEN:${GITLAB_CI_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" 
    - git push -o ci.skip --tags "https://GITLAB_CI_TOKEN:${GITLAB_CI_TOKEN}@$
```

... `pages:deploy` succeeds (but obviously I don't get updated CHANGELOG.md and release tag back in the repo)

[image]

I have by now reached the conclusion that `pages:deploy` somehow does not like that I pushed into repo in previous CI step. But I cannot find a way to further debug this.

Any help appreciated.

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

image: python:latest

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python --version  # For debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate

  - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
  - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
  - git config --global http.sslVerify false

release:
  stage: build
  script:
    - pip install python-semantic-release==9.1.1
    - git checkout main
    - git pull --rebase
    - git fetch --depth 1000 --prune --prune-tags --tags --force # Remove stale tags
    - git tag
    # Create a new version, release and tag. Also update CHANGELOG.md. If no new version will be created, then force update of changelog with unreleased items.
    - >
      semantic-release --verbose --strict --config .semantic-release/semantic-release.json version --skip-build --changelog --no-push --no-vcs-release || (semantic-release --verbose --config .semantic-release/semantic-release.json changelog; git add CHANGELOG.md; git -c user.name="semantic-release" -c user.email="semantic-release" commit -m"release: Unreleased items added to CHANGELOG.md" || true )  

    # Push the release commit first
    - git push -o ci.skip "https://GITLAB_CI_TOKEN:${GITLAB_CI_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" 
    # Push release tag
    - git push -o ci.skip --tags "https://GITLAB_CI_TOKEN:${GITLAB_CI_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" 
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 5 minutes
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - git checkout main
    - git pull --rebase
    - git fetch --depth 1000 --prune --prune-tags --tags --force # Remove stale tags

    # A bare minium needed to build documentation
    - pip install sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme

    # Any additional packages (custom themes, parsers and sphinx extensions) will be mentioned in requirements.txt
    - (cd docs && pip install -r requirements.txt )

    # Start the build
    - (cd docs && make html) 

    # Copy html documentation to public where it can be seen by GitLab Pages:
    - rm -rf public || true
    - mkdir public || true
    - mv docs/build/html/* public
    - ls -la public

    # - cat public/index.html
    - echo "Pages accessible through ${CI_PAGES_URL}/${PAGES_PREFIX}"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 5 minutes
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```